# Change text color based on text input inserted in database

Tags: javascript, json

The code I have shown below is a json object which is fetched from my sql database using getURI function. And all this information will be displayed in details.html if only when user click on one of the listview list. If user not click on any in the list, the listview will stay on the page status.html.

so this is my code for json:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "FYPphp/json.php";
    $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
            var id = field.id;
            var name = field.name;
            var ic = field.ic;
            var phone = field.phone;
            var home = field.home;
            var vehicle = field.vehicle;
            var plat = field.plat;
            var color = field.color;
            var wash = field.wash;
            var stat = field.stat;
            $("#listview").append("<a class='item' href='details.html?id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&ic=" + ic + "&phone=" + phone + "&home=" + home + "&vehicle=" + vehicle + "&plat=" + plat + "&color=" + color + "&wash=" + wash + "'><span class='item-note'><p>" + stat + "</p></span><h2>" + name + " </h2></a>");
        });
    });
});
```

If you look on the append method, there is variable called "stat" (in class item-note). For this variable, it might have three value in sql table which are "done","pending" or "cancel" that user can insert from details.html. The code of selection for variable "stat" in details.html:

```
<div class="item">
    <strong>Mark this entry as: </strong>
        <select id="stat">
            <option id="done">Done</option>
            <option id="pending">Pending</option>
            <option id="cancel">Cancel</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

The button for update "stat" variable is like this:

```
$("#update").click(function() {
    var id = $("#id").val();
    var stat = $("#stat").val();
    var dataString = "id=" + id + "&stat=" + stat + "&update=";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FYPphp/update.php",
        data: dataString,
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#update").val('Updating...');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == "success") {
                alert("Updated!");
                $("#update").val("Update");
            } else if (data == "error") {
                alert("error");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I want make these value display by their own color in the listview (in class item-note) where green for "done", yellow for "pending" and red for "cancel". [This is a screenshot of the listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB1JH.jpg)

Is there any chance I be able to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing something but.... cant you just set it when creating the  ?

```
$("#listview").append("<a class='item' href='details.html?id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&ic=" + ic + "&phone=" + phone + "&home=" + home + "&vehicle=" + vehicle + "&plat=" + plat + "&color=" + color + "&wash=" + wash + "'><span class='item-note'><p>" + stat + "</p></span><h2>" + name + " </h2></a>");
```

you can do something like setting a class name or something based on the field "stat".

```
var bgColor = (stat == "done" ? "green" : (stat == "pending" ? "yellow" : "red");
$("#listview").append("<a class='item "+bgColor+"' href='details.html?id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&ic=" + ic + "&phone=" + phone + "&home=" + home + "&vehicle=" + vehicle + "&plat=" + plat + "&color=" + color + "&wash=" + wash + "'><span class='item-note'><p>" + stat + "</p></span><h2>" + name + " </h2></a>");
```

Comment: Your solution worked for variable "stat" dynamically change text from done to green or pending to yellow and else to red. But not literally change the color of text. I tried using '<span style="color:green">"+stat+"</span>' after ? but nothing seems worked.

Comment: Ok, I think first you must understand this: You're building a string. You are constructing the text yourself. Therefore, first of all you must be sure what you're trying to accomplish, in HTML. In my examplei don't change "text". it's supossed to add a css class to the resulting (appended) item. The classname (green red or yellow) calculated and stored in the bgColor variable and that variable concatenated to the final string. Having that in mind, If you create these css classes, you can control the look of the 3 states from the css. So..1) resolve class name 2) add css class 3) add to item

Comment: What I mean is first you must understand what you're building. There are too many ways to make this work. I recomment you see where your "item" class is defined. Also see that my code adds "bgColor" next to item. So I'm adding a new css class. You must go wherever "item" is set and and in there the 3 new classes red green and yellow.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your explanation. It help me a lot :D